# NoMethodError: private method `permit' called for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I had my application up and running on heroku but suddenly it stopped working and when i checked the logs it says

> NoMethodError: private method `permit' called for #<
>   Devise::ParameterSanitizer

I had the following function in application_controller.rb for 5 months never caused error except now

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name , :account,:first_name, :last_name])
end
```

Can anyone help me on this ???

**UPDATE**
I forgot to mention that everything works fine on localhost

Comment: did you get the proper solution for this?

Comment: @Swaps check the answer below

Comment: `for` method is now obsolete But anyway, my problem resolved after restarting a server 2-3 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
  registration_params = [:name , :account,:first_name, :last_name]

  if params[:action] == 'create'
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do
      |u| u.permit(registration_params)
    end
  end
end
```

This may help you

Comment: @ImranNaqvi please check this for more information https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/3901

Comment: just came to know that .for method is deprecated in 4.1+ and is showing the error too. i'm curious why it's been working for last 5 months